# Can I use Apache mesos to manage a cluster as a whole entity?

Tags: mesos

For example, I have 20 machines and I split them into two clusters with 10 machines in each cluster. I know mesos can manage the 20 individual machines. But I want mesos to treat each cluster(with 10 machines) as an entity, other than treating 20 machines as 20 entities. Can mesos do that?

Comment: IMO this is currently not possible.

Answer (score 0):

This is not currently possible with Mesos. You could possibly implement it on top of Mesos -- for example, build a Mesos scheduler that groups together resources at multiple machines and then allows client applications to make use of those resources.

You could hypothetically do it with a future version of Mesos. At present, a Mesos resource (e.g., some CPUs or disk) must be local to a single agent node. There has been some discussion of extending the resource model to support "cluster-wide" or "global" resources, such as external storage arrays or software licenses (see [MESOS-2728](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MESOS-2728)), but that isn't currently implemented -- if it was, you might be able to generalize that.